# Identification of Lunar mare (maria) from a taken picture

Tags: the-moon

I'm in Brisbane right now. I took this picture 15 minutes ago from my balcony.

[image]

Could you help me with identification of marked Lunar maria? I cannot compare any of these to [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/61/Moon_names.svg) map.

I think 1 is **Mare Serenitatis** and 2 is **Mare Tranquillitatis**. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So your image looks more like this, with the red line being the terminator. The illuminated side in your image is the left side of the reference image, turned upside down.  I think you've gotten it backwards, the mare that you've labeled "1" is the Sea of Tranquility, and the one you've labeled "2" is the Sea of Serenity.

[image: Your image is upside down]

Comment: The moon in Australia is upside down (which might be the source of the OP's confusion), as noted in http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11867/where-exactly-does-the-moon-flip-given-that-it-appears-the-other-way-up-in-the

Comment: Now I see it @Maggie. You're right. Thanks! :)